# asp.net mvc ajax json undifined data to datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have an ajax call that brings data to fill my datatable.

My controller code is

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            var list = Json(new { data =  _db.Indicador.ToList() });
            return Json(new { data = await _db.Indicador.ToListAsync() });
        }
```

I set the var list a breakpoint to see the data.

[image]

I also have the default index table and the datatables added.
[image]

The first and the second column has data, but datatables is not showing it to me.

For my javascript I have.

```
function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#DT_load').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [{
            "defaultContent": "-",
            "targets": "_all"
        }],
        "ajax": {
            "url": '/api/indicador',
            "type": "GET",
            "dataType": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "Nombre_Indicador", "width": "20%" },
            { "data": "Descripcion_Indicadores", "width": "20%" },
            { "data": "medida", "width": "20%" },
            { "data": "objetivo", "width": "20%" },
            { "data": "perfil", "width": "20%" },
            { "data": "ponderacion", "width": "20%" },
            { "data": "base", "width": "20%" },
            { "data": "meta", "width": "20%" },
            {
                "data": "id_indicador",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `<div class="text-center">
<a href="/Indicadores/Edit?id=${data}" class='btn btn-success text-white' style='cursor:pointer; width:70px;'>
Editar
</a>
&nbsp;
<a class='btn btn-danger text-white' style='cursor:pointer; width:70px;'
onclick=Delete('/api/indicador?id='+${data})>
Eliminar
</a>
</div>`;
                }, "width": "40%"
            }
        ],
        "language": {
            "emptyTable": "no se encontraron datos"
        },
        "width": "100%"
    })
}
```

So there seems to be no data for 3 columns: Nombre_Indicador, Descripcion_Indicadores, and id_indicador.

I have no idea what's happening here, since those data are coming from the database.

Comment: Did you check the network tab, if those values are indeed arriving on the client? Could this be a casing issue? All the columns, that are working are lowercase on the client, yet on the server they all begin with uppercase letters. Try changing the columns "data" values to lowercase.

Comment: @ferikeem I changed to lowercase letters but no luck, also the network shows me the info inside the json, and shows as follows:
{"data":[{"id_Indicador":2,"usuario":null,"nombre_Indicador":"Venta de Carros BM","descripcion_Indicadores":"Indicador de ventas","medida":554,"objetivo":564,"perfil":"secretaria","ponderacion":10,"base":8,"meta":10}]}
there is only one null value, but I dont need to show it in the datatable

Comment: Don't change _everything_ to lowercase letters - just the leading letter. More specifically, make sure you use the _exact_ names as shown in the browser's network tool. So, for example, use `nombre_Indicador`. But do not use `Nombre_Indicador`, or `nombre_indicador`. The names used by DataTables must exactly match what is in the raw JSON data.

Comment: @andrewjames That's it, I changed the names, the leading letter to lower, now I can see the data on the datatabes.